# Configure iTunes to equalize based on "Genre" tag?

Tags: itunes

Is there a way to configure iTunes to configure the equalizer based on "Genre" tag of a given song?

Answer (score 2):

The first method that comes to mind :

1. Click on *Genre* column header to
   sort your songs based on genre
2. Select all songs belonging to a
   given genre.
3. *<kbd>Option</kbd>+I* to bring information dialog, go to *Options* tab
4. Select *Equalizer Preset* that corresponds to the genre

Repeat steps 2 to 4 for each genre.